# Difference between times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found the following code which is working well for a time sheet calculator I am using

```
function convertSecondsToHHMMSS(intSecondsToConvert) {
    var hours = convertHours(intSecondsToConvert);
    var minutes = getRemainingMinutes(intSecondsToConvert);
    minutes = (minutes == 60) ? "00" : minutes;
    var seconds = getRemainingSeconds(intSecondsToConvert);
    return hours+" hrs "+minutes+" mins";
}

function convertHours(intSeconds) {
    var minutes = convertMinutes(intSeconds);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
    return hours;
}

function convertMinutes(intSeconds) {
    return Math.floor(intSeconds/60);
}

function getRemainingSeconds(intTotalSeconds) {
    return (intTotalSeconds%60);
}

function getRemainingMinutes(intSeconds) {
    var intTotalMinutes = convertMinutes(intSeconds);
    return (intTotalMinutes%60);
}

function HMStoSec1(T) { 
  var A = T.split(/\D+/) ; return (A[0]*60 + +A[1])*60 + +A[2] 
}

var time1 = HMStoSec1("10:00:00");
var time2 = HMStoSec1("12:05:00");
var diff = time2 - time1;
document.write(convertSecondsToHHMMSS(diff));
```

It works fine when time1 is greater than time2, if time1 is less than time2 an extra hour is subtracted eg.

```
var time1 = HMStoSec1("09:00:00");
var time2 = HMStoSec1("08:55:00");
var diff = time2 - time1;
document.write(convertSecondsToHHMMSS(diff)); // writes "1 hr 5 mins" instead of "0 hr 5 mins"
```

I think its something to do with the Math.floor in the convertHours function.

I am trying to build something that can just take hours and minutes and subtract/add time, not actually times just quantities of hours and minutes.

There must be a simpler way that sadly eludes me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floor works different than most people expect for negative numbers.  It returns the next integer less than the operand, so for -1.5 it will return -2.  The easiest way to deal with this is just to take the absolute value (`Math.abs`) then add the negative sign back at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much, now just gotta work out how to do graveyard shift :(